# Infix expression (with negative numbers) to postfix

Tags: java, math-expression-eval

I am writing a class to evaluate an arithmetic expression, For now my class can convert an infix expression into postfix, it doesn't support exponents yet.

```
    public class Evaluator {
        public Map<String, Operator> mOperators = new HashMap<>();

        public Evaluator() {
            addOperator(new Operator("+", 1) {
                @Override
                public BigDecimal eval(BigDecimal a, BigDecimal b) {
                    return a.add(b);
                }
            });

            addOperator(new Operator("-", 1) {
                @Override
                public BigDecimal eval(BigDecimal a, BigDecimal b) {
                    return a.subtract(b);
                }
            });

            addOperator(new Operator("*", 2) {
                @Override
                public BigDecimal eval(BigDecimal a, BigDecimal b) {
                    return a.multiply(b);
                }
            });

            addOperator(new Operator("/", 2) {
                @Override
                public BigDecimal eval(BigDecimal a, BigDecimal b) {
                    return a.divide(b);
                }
            });
        }

        public String toPostfix(String infix) {
            Stack<String> operators = new Stack<>();
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String[] tokens = infix.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("(?<=[^.a-zA-Z\\d])|(?=[^.a-zA-Z\\d])");

            for (String token : tokens) {
                if (token.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
                    result.append(token).append(" ");
                } else if (operators.isEmpty() || operators.peek().equals("(") || token.equals("(")) {
                    operators.push(token);
                } else if (token.equals(")")) {
                    while (!operators.peek().equals("(")) {
                        result.append(operators.pop()).append(" ");
                    }
                    operators.pop();
                } else {
                    while (!operators.isEmpty() && precedence(operators.peek()) >= precedence(token)) {
                        result.append(operators.pop()).append(" ");
                    }
                    operators.push(token);
                }
            }

            while (!operators.isEmpty()) {
                result.append(operators.pop()).append(" ");
            }

            return result.toString().trim();
        }

        public void addOperator(Operator operator) {
            mOperators.put(operator.getSymbol(), operator);
        }

        private int precedence(String token) {
            Operator operator = mOperators.getOrDefault(token, null);
            return operator == null ? -1 : operator.getPrecedence();
        }

        public abstract class Operator {
            private final String mSymbol;
            private final int mPrecedence;

            public Operator(String symbol, int precedence) {
                mSymbol = symbol;
                mPrecedence = precedence;
            }

            public abstract BigDecimal eval(BigDecimal a, BigDecimal b);

            public String getSymbol() {
                return mSymbol;
            }

            public int getPrecedence() {
                return mPrecedence;
            }
        }
}
```

**My questions are:**

1. How to deal with negative number, e.g: `(-1) + 2`
2. Is there any easier or better way to evaluate an arithmetic
   expression without having to turn it into postfix?
3. What can I do to optimize my class and make it better?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Your question is fine, but I would remove the negative number question. We're here to review the current code, we're not coding new functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The two most common approaches to evaluating simple mathematical expressions are :

1. Parse the expression into an Abstract Syntax Tree, and then evaluate the tree.
2. Process the expression using Dijkstra's [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Answer (score -1):

Is there any reason to not use the great built-in expression evaluator: Nashorn Javascript Engine?

It can calculate for you all sorts of expressions supported by ES6. Example of usage (in Java 9):

```
@Test
public void calculate() throws ScriptException {
    String MATH_EXPR = "-1 + x * 2";
    Bindings bindings = new SimpleBindings( new HashMap<>( Map.of("x", 2) ) );
    Double result = (Double) jse.eval(MATH_EXPR, bindings);
    out.printf("x = %d, %s = %.1f%n", bindings.get("x"), MATH_EXPR, result);
    assertEquals( Double.valueOf(3.0), result );
}
```